# What is the "sense" of a command line option?

Tags: c, command-line-interface, command-line-arguments, glib

I am reading the documentation for [glib's CLI option parser](https://developer-old.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-Commandline-option-parser.html) and I'm very confused about one of their [option flags](https://developer-old.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-Commandline-option-parser.html#GOptionFlags).

> G_OPTION_FLAG_REVERSE
>
> For options of the [`G_OPTION_ARG_NONE`](https://developer-old.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-Commandline-option-parser.html#G-OPTION-ARG-NONE:CAPS) kind, this flag indicates that the sense of the option is reversed.

What does this mean? What is the "sense" of an option"?

Comment: Check  the [commit](https://git.tmon8.ru/comminux/glib/commit/5ddd4874a6bf6599a194bbc29b4f2b637e069ebb)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If an option does not take an argument, it can be considered boolean. The option is usually considered 'true' if present, or 'false' if absent. Those interpretations can be reversed, and that changes the sense of the option.